# Differnce between mvc and silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

which is future of web technology of microsoft 
silverlight or mvc asp.net i am really confused
iam good in asp.net but completely unaware with silvelight and mvc

Answer (score 2):

[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) is a [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) technology from Microsoft, best thought of as a Flash competitor. It uses [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) as a markup language.

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is a software pattern, but also used as part the name of a [web application framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) by Microsoft that utilizes this pattern - [ASP.NET-MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It is an alternative to webforms (ASP.NET) - noted for being easier to write tests for and for plug-ability of IoC containers, view engines and more.

Comment: MVC in general is not invented by Microsoft. I think you refer to ASP MVC 1/2/3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller

Comment: @Marcus - I have linked to both ASP.NET-MVC and the wikipedia MVC page that you linked to already. Perhaps you didn't read my answer fully?

Comment: I answered before you edited. So disregard my comment.